# How to iterate over 2D array in Twig template?

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, for-loop, twig

Please be gentle... relatively new to PHP/Symfony/Twig...

I have a colleague's code that performs a REST call to an F5, and builds an array consisting of a subset of the result set.  The array will have three "columns" and one or more rows.  Here is an example:

```
    array(3) { 
[0]=> array(3) {
    ["condition"]=> string(8) "Contains"
    ["uri"]=> string(10) "/1234/kkkl"
    ["pool"]=> string(50) "/Common/gateway-test-in-proc.domain.net_4041"
}
[1]=> array(3) {
    ["condition"]=> string(8) "Contains"
    ["uri"]=> string(34) "/portal_WS/1.0/authenticateMember"
    ["pool"]=> string(50) "/Common/gateway-test-in-proc.domain.net_4061"
}
[2]=> array(3) {
    ["condition"]=> string(9) "Ends With"
    ["uri"]=> string(20) "/Acknowledgement"
    ["pool"]=> string(50) "/Common/gateway-test-in-proc.domain.net_4011"
}
```

Below is the line of Symfony/PHP code that populates one 'row' of data in the array.  This line is inside a loop, and will create multiple rows in the array.

```
$twigdata[]=array('condition'=>$condition,'uri'=>$uri,'pool'=>$pool);
```

Here's a fragment of the Twig code within the body where I want to render the values.  If I do a print_r or vardump, I see the array contents just fine.

```
                {% for rulerecord in rulerecords %}
                <tr class="detailRowClass">
                    <td class="conditionClass">{{ rulerecord.condition }}</td>
                    <td class="URIclass">{{ rulerecord.uri }}</td>
                    <td class="poolClass">{{ rulerecord.pool }}</td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
```

Q.  Why do I only see a blank browser page?  What am I missing?

Comment: Does the final array you pass to twig contain a key `rulerecords`? Also a blank page could mean a fatal error with `display_errors=Off`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, Yoshi.  I found my bug!  Missing the "return" directive in the "render" statement.

Answer (score 1):

A. I found the answer to my silly mistake. The Twig code was just fine. I was missing the "return" directive. Here is the corrected line in the function that that renders the Twig:

return $this->render('netsecBundle:DataPower:datapower.html.twig', array('rulerecords'=>$twigdata));

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked to make sure the variable name being passed $twigdata in your controller is called rulerecords? If not change the variable in the for loop to match the controller variable being put into the view.

For example, try changing this:

```
$this->render('template_path', array('some_var' => $twigdata));
```

To this:

```
$this->render('template_path', array('rulerecords' => $twigdata));
```